# Query is really slow when dealing with millions of records. Need help to optimise

Tags: mysql

I'm running this query

```
mysql> explain SELECT
    recipients.id
FROM
    recipients
JOIN recipient_contact_details ON recipient_contact_details.recipient_id = recipients.id
JOIN recipient_contact_preferences ON recipient_contact_preferences.recipient_id = recipients.id
LEFT JOIN recipient_has_recipient_tags ON recipient_has_recipient_tags.recipient_id = recipients.id
LEFT JOIN recipient_tags ON recipient_tags.id = recipient_has_recipient_tags.recipient_tag_id
LEFT JOIN recipient_tag_groups ON recipient_tag_groups.id = recipient_tags.recipient_tag_group_id
INNER JOIN location ON location.id = recipients.location_id
WHERE
    1 = 1
AND FLOOR(
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), recipients.dob) / 365
) > 15
AND recipients.`join_date` < '2016-02-27 16:35:46'
AND recipients.`last_attendance` > '2016-02-18 16:35:46'
AND location.deleted_at IS NULL
AND recipient_contact_details.type = 1
AND recipient_contact_details.
VALUE
    != '';
```

(I apologise for the length!) - It *should* return around 900+k rows, from a recipients table of 2.7+m records. Which, it does, but it takes around 25-30 seconds to run.

After running an `explain` I can see:

```
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                         | type   | possible_keys                                                    | key                                                              | key_len | ref                                                     | rows  | Extra                                                           |
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | location                      | ALL    | PRIMARY,location_id_index                                        | NULL                                                             | NULL    | NULL                                                    |   156 | Using where                                                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | recipients                    | ref    | PRIMARY,recipients_location_id_index                             | recipients_location_id_index                                     | 5       | homestead.location.id                                   | 17918 | Using index condition; Using where                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | recipient_contact_preferences | ref    | recipient_contact_preferences_recipient_id_index                 | recipient_contact_preferences_recipient_id_index                 | 4       | homestead.recipients.id                                 |     1 | Using where; Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | recipient_has_recipient_tags  | ref    | recipient_has_recipient_tags_recipient_id_recipient_tag_id_index | recipient_has_recipient_tags_recipient_id_recipient_tag_id_index | 4       | homestead.recipients.id                                 |     2 | Using where; Using index                                        |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | recipient_contact_details     | ref    | recipient_contact_details_recipient_id_index                     | recipient_contact_details_recipient_id_index                     | 4       | homestead.recipients.id                                 |     2 | Using index condition; Using where                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | recipient_tags                | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                          | PRIMARY                                                          | 4       | homestead.recipient_has_recipient_tags.recipient_tag_id |     1 | Using where                                                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | recipient_tag_groups          | index  | PRIMARY                                                          | PRIMARY                                                          | 4       | NULL                                                    |     2 | Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
+----+-------------+-------------------------------+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------------------------+-------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
7 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

As you can see, I've already added (what I think are relevant indexes to the various tables) . The location table is

```
    mysql> desc location;
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| Field            | Type             | Null | Key | Default             | Extra          |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
| id               | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL                | auto_increment |
| created_at       | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| updated_at       | timestamp        | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |                |
| name             | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| deleted_at       | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL                |                |
| org_website      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| from_name        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| reply_to_address | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| logo_path        | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| colour           | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| street_address   | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| city             | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| region           | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| postcode         | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| country          | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| privacy_url      | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL                |                |
| remote_id        | bigint(20)       | NO   | MUL | 0                   |                |
+------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------------------+----------------+
17 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

I'm quite new to optimising queries for such a large result set. I can see that the location table is having issues, but I'm unsure as to what to change to make a difference. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? Some feedback would be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please create an index on recipients.dob

```
CREATE INDEX idx_recipients_dob ON recepients(dob);
```

and rewrite this:

```
AND FLOOR(
    DATEDIFF(NOW(), recipients.dob) / 365
) > 15
```

to this:

```
AND recipients.dob < NOW() - INTERVAL 15 YEAR
```

I think, this might already solve all your problems.
The rewrite is necessary, because MySQL can't use an index if there's any calculation on the indexed column. Plus it's easier to read and more accurate (you're forgetting leap years).

And these joins

```
LEFT JOIN recipient_has_recipient_tags ON recipient_has_recipient_tags.recipient_id = recipients.id
LEFT JOIN recipient_tags ON recipient_tags.id = recipient_has_recipient_tags.recipient_tag_id
LEFT JOIN recipient_tag_groups ON recipient_tag_groups.id = recipient_tags.recipient_tag_group_id
```

are not necessary when you don't use these tables anyway.